# Functions sem_post, sem_wait and sleep

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

> Machine A produces an item every 2 seconds. The AA machine assembles a
>   product from 2 items that machine A had produced.
>
> An AA machine can assemble a product every second, but it needs 2
>   items per product, so AA is waiting for 2 items from Machine A.
>
> Each machine works in an endless loop, but the factory closes after 20
>   seconds and does not wait for the machines to finish working.
>
> Write a program that allows the factory and the machines in it,
>   organized work according to the requirements of the factory.

I have the following output, and my code needs to output the same.

[image: Output]

I write this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t sem1;

void* Machine_A() {
    while(1) {
        printf("Produced A\n");
        sleep(2);   
        sem_post(&sem1);
    }
}

void* Machine_AA() {
    while(1) {
        sem_wait(&sem1);
        sem_wait(&sem1);
        printf("Collected AA\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threadA, threadAA;
    sem_init(&sem1, 0, 0);
    pthread_create(&threadA, NULL, Machine_A, NULL);
    pthread_create(&threadAA, NULL, Machine_AA, NULL );
    sleep(20);
    return 0;
}
```

and I get this output:

[image: 3TimesPrinted]

I don't understand why machine A prints 3 times at first time and after that it works well.

If I change the code of machine A:

```
void* Machine_A() {
    while(1) {
        printf("Produced A\n");
        sem_post(&sem1);
        sleep(2);
    }
}
```

I get the right output.

I don't understand why it prints `Produced A` 3 times.
Every time `sem_wait` blocks until it becomes possible to perform the decrement.

Thanks!!

Comment: Get rid of the 'sleep(1); in 'Machine_AA()'   Why did you puit that in anyway?

Comment: Brilliantly written question! If you don't get an answer in a few hours, you can nag me about it because I think I sort of know but I'm not certain precisely.

Comment: @MartinJames Because AA machine can assemble a product every second.

Comment: You have a race condition where thread 1 can call sem_post and printf before thread 2's second sem_wait returns.

Comment: You print "Produced A" when you *start* the "production" (before the `sleep()`), but a sane interpretation of "produced" (past tense) would only make sense if you printed "Produced A" when the sleep finishes.

Comment: @Shawn, Why always `threadA`  prints 3 times, after all race condition result need to be nondeterministic ?

Comment: @EOF, When I change that and write `sleep(2)` in the beginning of the loop, it works.
Why?
Thanks.

Comment: @Asaf Well, after `Machine_A()` does its second `sem_post()`, it can immediately continue executing the loop, reaching `printf()` again. On the other hand, `Machine_AA()` was blocked before, and the thread needs to be woken up by the operating system. Which of them is faster will depend on how the OS schedules threads.

Comment: @EOF, So, if I run this in another operating system, then may it print 3 times `Produced A`?

Comment: @Asaf What I meant is that your *original code* could potentially produce the output you expected, if the OS scheduler happens to like you. With the changed code, the scheduler would have to keep the newly unblocked thread from executing while the unblocking thread sleeps in order for the wrong output to appear. That is certainly possible, and using time to synchronize tasks is generally a terrible idea, but you probably will not see unexpected output unless the machine the code is running on is horrifically slow and/or overloaded.

Comment: @EOF What is the right way to solve the exercise without using time dependency(calling `sleep()`)?

Thanks.

Comment: @Asaf Use a second  semaphore. However, it's quite likely that noticing the variable timing-dependent behavior is the intent of the exercise in the first place. Also, if the code is correctly synchronized, care has to be taken to preserve parallelism.